# How to fix viewport being tilted on startup?

Tags: 3d-view, startup-file

I just started using Blender 2.90.1 a few days ago, and noticed that whenever I create a new .blend file, the viewport appeared just *slightly* tilted. I thought I was going crazy, until I used "Align Active Camera to View" to inspect the transform of the viewport's camera, and Rotation Y was set to 0.76 degrees. It's miniscule, but I work with a lot of geometric shapes, so I *definitely* notice it, and it bothers the hell out of me.
Additionally, once I do manage to fix the view (by switching to Front and then panning around), the viewport in other Workspaces do not change--they still are tilted.
Is there a way to make Blender start up with *all* viewports not tilted this way?

Below is the transform values of the initial viewport camera position:
[image: Initial Values]

Comment: Switching to front view and panning around will change orientation and position of viewport camera. There is view from render camera shown on the screenshot. So orientation of which one do you want to change? If you edit location / orientation of render camera in one workspace it'll be changed for others since it's one object

Comment: I'm not trying to change the orientation of the render camera. I just used "Align Active Camera to View" to demonstrate that, when it aligns to the initial viewport perspective, upon inspecting the transform values, it is rotated. My issue has nothing to do with the render camera.

Comment: I've noticed the tilt as well - don't know why it's there. I've found the best way to get rid of it, though is to switch to one of the side views (Numpad 1 or 3), and then pan from there. I normally do this several times throughout modelling anyway - I guess it just feels good to have a refreshed "axis alignment" from time to time.

Comment: Question is, what startup view rotation do you want. As is with y euler set to 0?  Once you have the view orientation the way you wish, (for one or all 3d views in each workspace)  save the startup file to make it "default".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The 3d view's view_rotation**

This is purely an arbitrary choice in the default startup file. Edit and save the startup file if any are not to your liking.

Instead of aligning a camera to view, can get the view matrix of the 3d view.

For example, looking at the 3d view rotation of the 3d viewport in General Workspace.

```
>>> s = D.workspaces['General'].screens[0].areas[3].spaces.active

>>> list(map(degrees, s.region_3d.view_rotation.to_euler()))
[63.52429048891948, 0.7600397052594825, 65.79110050085248]
```

showing the 0.76 degrees result for y Euler rotation.  Like a camera the view looks down its local Z axis.

Test script to change all 3d views in all workspaces to have a zero euler rotation y component.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

for ws in bpy.data.workspaces:
    for screen in ws.screens:
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                r3d = area.spaces.active.region_3d
                eul = r3d.view_rotation.to_euler()
                eul.y = 0
                r3d.view_rotation = eul.to_quaternion()
```

Result of above after running script

```
>>> list(map(degrees, s.region_3d.view_rotation.to_euler()))
[63.52429048891948, -9.830594791652178e-07, 65.79110050085248]
```

(y rot value is `-0.000000983` which can be considered zero within blenders tolerance limit)

To make these permanent, open new file, paste script in text editor, run script, (unlink after running to not save script) then save startup file. *`File > Defaults > Save Startup File`* Now any new file will reflect this change.

For other templates would need to open and edit the blend file associated with the template [look for link].

Comment: Could be wrong (_more_ than likely).. but .76 Y in this case is not pitch (local Camera Y), but Global Euler Y, in Gimbal space? i.e. given XYZ rotation order? So it's more like a yaw? But my head is spinning more than the camera... Anyhow, that all doesn't explain how the annoying roll got there in the first place.

Comment: @RobinBetts  lol...thought to self that it's not  pitch after I wrote it. Forgot to re-edit on a couple of edits.  Was in hindsight thinking its a local roll.  You're prob right with yaw (or combo of both) . There is a q somewhere re Tait Bryant -> pitch, roll, yaw.